# How can I model a database view in Django if it doesn't have a primary key?

Tags: django, django-models, view

I have a database view that relates 2 companies by foreign keys like so:

DB company_view:

```
  company1_id FK to Company,
  company2_id FK to Company,
  description text
where
  --- some company criteria ---
```

I try model in Django as unmanaged like so:

```
class CompanyView(models.Model):
  company1 = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='company1_id', parent_link=True)
  company2 = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='company2_id', parent_link=True)
  description = models.TextField()

  class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'company_view'
```

For the Admin class I have:

```
@admin.register(models.CompanyView)
class CompanyViewAdmin(AdvancedModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('company1', 'company2', 'description')
```

But the admin page throws exception like:

> psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column company_view.id does not exist

It doesn't make sense to have a primary id key, so is there any way around this?
Thanks

Comment: I cannot see the downside of adding a PK. AFAIK you cannot use django admin without a PK.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this by making ``unique_together = ('company1', 'company2')`` which the migration then converts to id field, which doesn't exist in view, so dead end :(

Answer (score 0):

why you dont make a many-to-many relationship?

```
company = models.ManyToManyField(Company)
```

look: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

this will solve your problem, since it use a object instance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry what I didn't mention is that the view is more complex with where conditions like company1.type = 'aaa' and company2.no_employees < 10 etc, so it needs to be unmanaged by Django.

Comment: you tried create a primary key for CompanyView? whats been happened?

Comment: I tried to make a "synthetic" id key like text(company1_id) || '_' || text(company2_id), which does show the data in admin, but if I click on item it fails with type error because Django tries to execute query " ... where company_view.id = xxx_yyy' expecting integer id which is not integer value..

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar problem and solved it by defining the id as being a hash value of the other columns of the view like so (database is postgreSQL):

```
select hashtext('<col1>'||'<col2>'||'<col3>'||'...') id, col1, col2 ...
```

Your model would look like this - using the id field as a fake primary key:

```
class CompanyView(models.Model):
  id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True) 
  company1 = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='company1_id', parent_link=True)
  company2 = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='company2_id', parent_link=True)
  description = models.TextField()

  class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'company_view'
```

Mabe a better solution than just setting an arbitrary field as primary ...